# How to grab specific API data

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, api

First of all the code itself is working, the only problem being is that I cannot target a specific set of data from the API as it automatically adjust.

I had been told to set at the value after the $json, via the use of ['value here'], from here the code will take the information from the API according to which number is entered.

However, this API is self-adjusting, so the person in rank 1 might change, however, I still want to target Jimmy and not another person.

**Is there any way to do this?**

I was thinking:

```
$jimmy = $json["jimmy"]["rank"]; #Grab the values.
```

But this did not work.

**My PHP code.**

```
<?php
$url = "linktotheapiishere"; #Grab API Data.
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); #Read the API contents.
$jimmy = $json[0]["rank"]; #Grab the values.
echo $jimmy;  #Print the values.
?>
```

**API Data:**

```
[
{
"id": "sample1", 
"name": jimmy", 
"rank": "1", 
}, 
{
"id": "sample2", 
"name": "john", 
"rank": "2", 
}, 
{
"id": "sample2", 
"name": "bob", 
"rank": "3", 
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work only if all names are unique

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); #Read the API contents.
// make name value as key of the array
$json = array_column($json, null, 'name');
$jimmy = $json['sample2']["rank"]; #Grab the values.
echo $jimmy;  #Print the values
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents("linktotheapiishere");
$json_data = json_decode($xml, true);
$jimmy = $json_data[0]["rank"];
?>
```